# woocommerce get 'billing_phone' field on checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_order_status_completed_sms', 10, 1);
function my_order_status_completed_sms($order_id){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $user_id = $order->get_customer_id();

    if($user_id){
        $phone_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_phone', true);

        if($phone_number){
            cosmosfarm_members_sms_send($phone_number, '#'.$order_id.' is complete. thank you!');
        }
    }
}
```

When someone purchases from a woocommerce, woocommerce send sms by plug-in.

but there's some issues.

If the buyer is a member, sms will be sent out normally, no problem.

However, if the buyer is not a guest, no sms will be sent.
What's the problem?

Comment: do you mean, "if the buyer is a guest" ?

Comment: To send it to guests too, you should remove simply `if($user_id){` and a closing `}`

Comment: @HowardE yes, i want send sms member and guest too.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i changed it, but noting happen.
`add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_order_status_completed_sms', 10, 1);
function my_order_status_completed_sms($order_id){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $user_id = $order->get_customer_id();


        $phone_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_phone', true);

        if($phone_number){
            cosmosfarm_members_sms_send($phone_number, '#'.$order_id.' is complete. thank you!');
        }

}`

Comment: how can i add code in comment pretty? damn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is dependend upon having user_id and getting the user_meta for that user.

```
function my_order_status_completed_sms( $order_id ) {
    // Get the order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // Get the billing phone number from the order
    $phone_number = $order->get_billing_phone();
    if ( $phone_number ) {
        cosmosfarm_members_sms_send( $phone_number, '#' . $order_id . ' is complete. thank you!' );
    }
}
```

Using the order object, the biling phone is there if entered for either customer or guest.